# /usr/bin/texi2dvi: cannot create directory

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, ubuntu-16.04

After upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04, whenever I use

```
knit2pdf(input="ABC.Rnw", quiet = TRUE)
```

in `RStudio Version 0.99.1197`, I get the following error:

> processing file: ./202Analysis.Rnw Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf
>   = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  :    Running 'texi2dvi' on 'ABC.tex' failed. Messages: mkdir: cannot create directory
>   ‘Yaseen/XYZ’: No such file or directory /usr/bin/texi2dvi: cannot
>   create directory: Yaseen/XYZ

**Edited**

My directory ‘Yaseen/XYZ STU’ is containing spaces. Everything works fine after removing these spaces. However the same code was working fine with Ubuntu 14.04. How can I make this (directory names containing spaces) workable with Ubuntu 16.04?

**Edited 2**

This [link](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html) says:

To build the PDF documentation, you will need a version of TeX Live or texinfo that includes texi2dvi (BEWARE: recent TeX Live, and some texinfo RPMs, do NOT include texi2dvi).

Comment: Have you created this directory or verified that it exists?

Comment: I think this is a problem with TeX. TeX doesn't handle spaces in filenames very well (or at all).

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam: More likely a problem in knitr: TeX isn't running `mkdir`.

Comment: On my machine with similar specifications it does not work with or without spaces in the path. And `texi2dvi` seems to be unaiavailable in the Ubuntu repositories. But why don't you use `knit` to create a `.tex` file and then use a `system` command to call for your LaTeX compiler ? For example : `setwd("Yaseen/XYZ STU/") ; knit(input="ABC.Rnw", quiet = TRUE) ; system("pdflatex ABC.tex")`. On my machine it works also when the working directory has spaces

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous comments in that the space in the directory seems to be the culprit.

Have you tried escaping the whitespace in your output directory?

```
knit2pdf(input="ABC.Rnw", quiet = TRUE, output = "Yaseen/XYZ\ STU")
```